How to remove /favicon.ico 404 Not Found log in Honojs
I want to use Honojs as a rest api sending only json on cloudflare workers
How can I remove this [wrangler:inf] GET /favicon.ico 404 Not Found log since I don't need a favicon in my case since I am never sending html

You could block those requests at a load balancer level if you wanted, but that is expected behaviour and is caused by whichever "client" you are using to make the HTTP request. For example, if you use Chrome search bar to make the request it'll always request that icon and there's nothing you can do
